# Overlloaded assignment operator for superclass

Tags: c++, class

So the question follows:

we have such class:

```
    class Boo : public SuperBoo {

Foo* fFoo1;

Foo* fFoo2;

// ...

}
```

, where foo is a monomorphic class. Now we need to overload assignment operator (=) for this class.

Comment: You should add the following to your checklist before pushing the "ask question" button : Check that there is a question-mark "?" somewhere in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, when you have a class hierarchy, it is often prudent **not to supply an assignment operator**. In fact, it's usually better to prevent assignment and copy construction:

```
class Example
{
    // ...
private:
    Example(Example const &);
    Example &operator=(Example const &);
};
```

Or in C++11:

```
class Example
{
    // ...
    Example(Example const &) = delete;
    Example &operator=(Example const &) = delete;
};
```

Assignment operators are typically useful for **value classes**, not for classes which have **identity**. In your example, the names don't tell us anything, really. But if your `Boo`is actually something like `GuiWidget`, `Driver`, `FileStream` or `ThreadWrapper`, i.e. something where object-oriented programming may actually be useful, then the concept of assignment no longer makes sense. What does it mean to assign one `GuiWidget` to another `GuiWidget`, or, for a more precise example, to assign a button to a dropdown menu?

Assigning is great for classes which do not refer to some other resource, for example `Matrix`, `Color`, `List` or `PostalAddress`. It certainly makes sense to assign one `Matrix` to another `Matrix`, or to assign a blue-color object to a red-color object.

Look at the standard library. You will notice that object-oriented classes like `std::ifstream` do not support assignment, whereas value classes like `std::list` do.

Your desire to support assignment for object-oriented classes probably has one of two reasons:

1. You want to support assignment because "it is natural and every C++ class should have it". That's just wrong.
2. You want something special to happen when you "assign". In the example from above, when "assigning" a button to a dropdown menu, you may just want to give the dropdown menu the same colors as the button. That's a valid desire, but `operator=` is then just a wrong (i.e. misleading, confusing) function name. You'd be better off naming the function something like `AssignStyleFrom`, and forbid assignment.

By preventing assignment for object-oriented classes, you also avoid all the nasty issues and the confusion that come with it. In Scott Meyers' *Effective C++* (or was it *More Effective C++*?), there is a whole chapter about the pitfalls of assignment operators in class hierarchies. By designing your program such that assignment operators are only provided by non-derivable value classes, you don't need to worry about those things anymore.

Answer (score 2):

```
class derived : public base {
    public:
        double *b;
        derived(double aParam, double bParam) : base(aParam) { 
            b = new double; *b = bParam; 
        }
        derived() : base() { 
            b = new double; *b = 0; }
        ~derived() { 
            delete b; 
        }
        derived(const derived &derivedParam) : base(derivedParam) { 
            b = new double; *b = *derivedParam.b; 
        }
        void show() { 
            cout << *a << " " << *b << endl; 
        }
        derived &operator=(const derived& derivedParam) { 
            *a = *derivedParam.a; *b = *derivedParam.b; return *this; 
        }
};

int main(){
    base *ptrB1, *ptrB2;
    derived objD1(5,6), objD2;
    ptrB1 = &objD1;
    ptrB2 = &objD2;
    *ptrB2 = *ptrB1;
    ptrB2->show();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have two pointers as data members, you will need to have an overloaded assignment operator (along with a destructor and a copy constructor) to make a deep copy of the pointers in case of an assignment

```
Boo::operator=( const Boo& obj) {
      Superboo::operator=obj //calling the assignment operator of the base explicitly
      fFoo1 = obj->fFoo1;
      fFoo2 = obj->fFoo2;
      return *this;
  }
```

Now, since Boo inherits from SuperBoo, you will have to explicitly call the assignment operator of the base class Superboo (if there is a non-default assignment operator defined for it.)